# How to find package by directory?

Tags: debian, apt

How can I find the package (in Debian) that contain a file with path that contains a certain substring?

Example: find all packages (installed or not) that contain a file with path that contains "`/usr/share/xml/`".

I have installed xsltproc and had no xml catalog for xhtml => it was looking for dtds over the net, being slow and ddosing W3C.

I knew that the catalog packages should be in /usr/share/xml/, but was unable to find packages that put files to the directory.

The search at https://packages.debian.org looks only for suffixes of package file paths, not the substrings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this locally by installing [`apt-file`](https://tracker.debian.org/apt-file):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search /usr/share/xml/
```

(depending on the version of Debian you're using, you may not need the `apt-file update` step).

Comment: That doesn't work for me, and according to `man apt-file` it should not work: "Since Contents files does not contain directories, the pattern must match (part of a) file name."

Comment: @AFoglia I’m not sure what’s going on in your case, but this worked for me when I wrote it, and it works for me now. Look at the `Contents` files, they contain full paths, and that’s what `apt-file` searches.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt install apt-file
```

Then run as root or with sudo `apt-file update` This updates the cache for apt-file from your apt sources.

You can search with `apt-file search for something`